# How to fix battery problems in Ubuntu 16.04 Acer Laptop with 940 MX?

Tags: battery, acer, bumblebee, tlp, bbswitch

My laptop used to get 12 hours of battery life in Windows. I'm getting only 2-3 in Ubuntu. Windows had software that would shut off the gpu unless it was required, however I don't think that Ubuntu has the same functionality. I've looked into tlp/powertop and bbswitch, but can't figure out if bbswitch will work for the 940 MX. Is there any way I can fix the laptop's battery life?